# How would I use local storage for a to do list?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am being asked to have a to do list and save each task (that the user supplies as well as original) through local storage. My teacher did a very simple demo on something completely different and I spent a few hours trying to figure it out. When I looked at the solution, I honestly cannot figure it out. It looks really complicated, and I don't even know where to start. If anyone can give me any hints, that would be awesome!

My code:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

let newItem = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

function output() {
    let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText = newItem.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo');
    let ulAppend = ul.append(newTodo);
    ul.append(newTodo);
    let checkboxAppend = newTodo.append(checkbox);
    newTodo.append(checkbox);
    newItem.value = '';
}

let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
button.addEventListener('click', output);

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        e.target.remove();
    } else if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('finished');
    }
});
```

My teacher's code/local storage solution:

```
const todoForm = document.getElementById("newTodoForm");
const todoList = document.getElementById("todoList");

// retrieve from localStorage
const savedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
for (let i = 0; i < savedTodos.length; i++) {
  let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  newTodo.innerText = savedTodos[i].task;
  newTodo.isCompleted = savedTodos[i].isCompleted ? true : false;
  if (newTodo.isCompleted) {
    newTodo.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo);
}

todoForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  let taskValue = document.getElementById("task").value;
  newTodo.innerText = taskValue;
  newTodo.isCompleted = false;
  todoForm.reset();
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo);

  // save to localStorage
  savedTodos.push({ task: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false });
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos));
});

todoList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let clickedListItem = event.target;

  if (!clickedListItem.isCompleted) {
    clickedListItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    clickedListItem.isCompleted = true;
  } else {
    clickedListItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    clickedListItem.isCompleted = false;
  }

  // breaks for duplicates - another option is to have dynamic IDs
  for (let i = 0; i < savedTodos.length; i++) {
    if (savedTodos[i].task === clickedListItem.innerText) {
      savedTodos[i].isCompleted = clickedListItem.isCompleted;
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos));
    }
  }
});
```

Even though my code is more simpler (at least from what I can tell), it works exactly as his code does.

Comment: You can store key-value pair in localstorage , value should be string. Idea could be something like , on load of the page check if the data is present in the local storage , show it . And when you do submit , you should push the data to local storage. There are methods : getItem and setItem methods of local storage. Please check on that .

Answer (score 0):

Local storage saves a JSON object to the user's computer. You should create an array of todos, append that array with every new todo, then set that item to local storage.

```
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

const savedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []; // Retrieves local storage todo OR creates empty array if none exist
let newItem = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

function output() {
    let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText = newItem.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo');
    ul.append(newTodo);
    newTodo.append(checkbox);

    savedTodos.push({task: newItem.value, isCompleted: false}); // Appends the new todo to array
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos)); //Converts object to string and stores in local storage

    newItem.value = '';
}
```

Comment: It stopped working all together? Or just the localStorage part? I used the code you provided and just added 3 lines.

Comment: The localStorage didn't work. I refresh and it doesn't stay on the page, though it is saved in localStorage

Answer (score 0):

The important part is in (de)serializing the data. That means:

- reading from `localStorage` (`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []`)

  We add the default `[]` because if the `todos` key does not exist, we will get `null` and we expect a *list*
- saving to `localStorage` (`localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos))`)

We need `JSON.parse` and its complementary operation `JSON.stringify` to parse and save strings because localStorage can store only strings.

In your case you need to read the data from localStorage and *render* the initial list. To save it to localStorage, again, you have to serialize the data. See the below snippets (link to working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9bwe1zm0/1/), because the below example does not work in the StackOverflow sandbox environment):

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

let newItem = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');

const Store = {
  serialize () {
    return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li")).map(c => {
      return {
        text: c.textContent,
        finished: c.querySelector("input").checked
      }
    })
  },
  get () {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []
  },
  save () {
    return localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(Store.serialize()))
  }
}

const firstItems = Store.get()
firstItems.forEach(it => {
  output(it.text, it.finished)
})

function output(v, finished) {
  let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = v || newItem.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo');
  let ulAppend = ul.append(newTodo);
  ul.append(newTodo);

  // Create a checkbox for each item
  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  if (finished) {
    checkbox.checked = true
  }
  checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

  let checkboxAppend = newTodo.append(checkbox);
  newTodo.append(checkbox);
  newItem.value = '';
}

let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    output()
  Store.save()
});

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.remove();
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('finished');
  }
  // Update the value in localStorage when you delete or add a new item
  Store.save()
});
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<input type="text" /> <button class="btn">Submit</button>
```

I have added the `Store` variable to simplify the way you get and set the data in localStorage.

The serialize method will read the TODOs from the list. `document.querySelectorAll("li")` returns a `NodeList`, but by doing `[].slice.call(...)` we convert it to an `Array`.

Comment: This looks as complicated as my teacher's answer. I am just learning and looking at this I don't know several things. For example, what does the following do/mean? :   serialize () {
    return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li")).map(c => {
      return {
        text: c.textContent // Also, are you setting variable store to multiple functions, is that what it is?

Comment: It looks like the variable store is an object of functions.But I don't see where they are defined? Can you define a variable to a variable.function()? (const firstItems = Store.get()) EDIT: Ohh, wait. Those functions are already defined in js, aren't they?

Comment: @Cutecat42 When we create such an object, that is a collection of functions defined right there: `myObj = { myMethod () {...} }`.

Comment: I just tried that code and it's not saving anything in local storage :(

Comment: @Cutecat42 I updated my code. I forgot doing save on adding a new todo.

Answer (score 0):

I've annotated the solution you posted with some comments to help you step through it.

```
// Retrieve elements and store them in variables
const todoForm = document.getElementById("newTodoForm");
const todoList = document.getElementById("todoList");

// Get data stored in localStorage under the key "todos".
// The data type will be a string (local storage can only store strings).
// JSON is a global object that contains methods for working with data represented as strings.
// The `||` syntax is an OR operator and is used here to set an empty array as a fallback in case `localStorage` is empty
const savedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];

// Create a loop the same length as the list of todos
for (let i = 0; i < savedTodos.length; i++) {
  // Create an <li> element in memory (does not appear in the document yet)
  let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  // Set the inner text of that new li with the contents from local storage.
  // The savedTodos[i] is accessing data in the localStorage array.
  // The [i] is a different number each loop.
  // The `.task` is accessing 'task' property on the object in the array.
  newTodo.innerText = savedTodos[i].task;
  // Create a new property on the element called `isCompleted` and assign a boolean value.
  // This is only accessible in code and will not show up when appending to the DOM.
  newTodo.isCompleted = savedTodos[i].isCompleted ? true : false;
  // Check the value we just set.
  if (newTodo.isCompleted) {
    // Create a style for the element if it is done (strike it out)
    newTodo.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }
  // Actually append the new element to the document (this will make it visible)
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo);
}

// `addEventListener` is a function that registers some actions to take when an event occurs.
// The following tells the browser - whenever a form is submitted, run this function.
todoForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // Don't try to send the form data to a server. Stops page reloading.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Create a <li> element in memory (not yet visible in the document)
  let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  // Find element in the document (probably a input element?) and access the text value.
  let taskValue = document.getElementById("task").value;
  // Set the text of the <li>
  newTodo.innerText = taskValue;
  // Set a property on the <li> call `isCompleted`
  newTodo.isCompleted = false;
  // Empty out all the input fields in the form
  todoForm.reset();
  // Make the new <li> visible in the document by attaching it to the list
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo);

  // `push` adds a new element to the `savedTodos` array. In this case, an object with 2 properties.
  savedTodos.push({ task: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false });
  // Overwrite the `todos` key in local storage with the updated array.
  // Use the JSON global object to turn an array into a string version of the data
  // eg [1,2,3] becomes "[1,2,3]"
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos));
});

// This tells the browser - whenever the todoList is clicked, run this function.
// The browser will call the your function with an object that has data about the event.
todoList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // the `target` of the event is the element that was clicked.
  let clickedListItem = event.target;

  // If that element has a property called `isCompleted` set to true
  if (!clickedListItem.isCompleted) {
    // update the styles and toggle the `isCompleted` property.
    clickedListItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    clickedListItem.isCompleted = true;
  } else {
    clickedListItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    clickedListItem.isCompleted = false;
  }

  // The code above changes the documents version of the data (the elements themselves)
  // This loop ensures that the array of todos data is kept in sync with the document
  // Loop over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < savedTodos.length; i++) {
    // if the item in the array has the same text as the item just clicked...
    if (savedTodos[i].task === clickedListItem.innerText) {
      // toggle the completed state
      savedTodos[i].isCompleted = clickedListItem.isCompleted;
      // Update the localStorage with the new todos array.
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(savedTodos));
    }
  }
});
```

Keep in mind, there are 2 sources of state in your todo list. One is how the document looks, and the other is the array of `todos` data. Lots of challenges come from making sure these 2 stay in sync.

If somehow the document showed one of the list items as crossed out, but your array of data shows that all the `todos` are *not completed*, which version is correct? There is no right answer here, but state management will be something you might consider when designing apps in the future. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is a good js library with a well understood pattern that helps solve this problem. Hope this last comment doesn't confuse too much. Best of luck!

Comment: Is it possible to save everything in local storage without using a loop? Also, in the teacher's solution, he does the strikethrough different than how I did it. I set a class toggle when clicked on the li. I'm just trying to figure out a solution that would work with my code without editing too much, if that makes sense.

Comment: There are 2 sources of state. The DOM elements themselves, and the array of data. When a todo is clicked, you need to change the visual style of the DOM element, but you also need to update the data in the array. The loop is used to update an item in the array. If you don't loop and update one of the items in the array, then your data and your view are out of sync. Setting `localStorage` without looping and updating the array would just re-save the old array data again.
I think in this case you need the loop.